# How can I present a UIViewController when a UITextField should begin editing?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I want to present a `UIViewController` when the user taps on the `dateTextField` and it should not begin editing. Here is my code:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if textField == dateTextField{
        datePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
        datePicker.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(datePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return false

    }else{
        return true

    }
}
```

I check if this `UITextField` is the `dateTextField`, but the View also appears when I tap in another `UITextField`. Why?

Comment: Is `dateTextField` an IBOutlet?

Comment: @chedabob Yes it is, but i already solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = textField;

    if (activeField == dobTextField ) {
        [activeField resignFirstResponder];
        [self showDatePickerView];
    } else if (activeField == countryTextField)  {

        [activeField resignFirstResponder];
        [self  showCountryPickerView];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I check if this UITextField is the dateTextField, but the View also appears when i tap in another TextField. Why?

because you use in `if textField == dateTextField{` `==` while you should use `===` which should be used when you check if the both sides is the same object

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: RBPTextField) -> Bool {

    if textField === dateTextField {

        self.endEditing(true)
        self.showDatePicker()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: It still shows the DatePicker, also when I tap in other `UITextField`s